# Reapplying Sort To DataGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have a DataGridView.

I can click the column headers to sort the data by whichever column header I click.

I have some functionality that clears the DataGridView, and repopulates it with data.  The problem I'm having is that the indication of a sort in a particular column (the gray upside up or upside down triangle) still remains even though the data isn't sorted by that column because it was just loaded into the DataGridView.

Is there any way I can reapply the sort right after the new data is added?

Edit: If this isn't very easy, just being able to get rid of that gray upside-up or upside-down triangle is good enough so it is clear that the data is not sorted.

Comment: I had a similar situation recently. I created a class that will handle all of my datagrid sorting. http://jspot.jerryhanel.com/2012/06/28/sort-your-databound-grid-effortlessly/

Answer (score 0):

This should do the remove

```
Column.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.None;
```

But if you read this, you should be able to extract what you need ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171608.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Before you repopulate, take a note of the sorted column, and afterwards reapply the sort: you might also want to preserve the current selected row, as otherwise it will be lost when you repopulate.

```
int? index = null;
int firstDisplayedRowIndex = 0;
int sortedColumnIndex = -1;
SortOrder sortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending;

if (dgv.CurrentRow != null)
{
    index = dgv.CurrentRow.Index;
    firstDisplayedRowIndex = dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;

    if (dgv.SortedColumn != null)
    {
        sortedColumnIndex = dgv.SortedColumn.Index;
        sortOrder = dgv.SortOrder;
    }
}

// Repopulate grid...

if (index.HasValue)
{
    if (sortedColumnIndex > -1)
    {
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case SortOrder.Ascending:
                dgv.Sort(dgv.Columns[sortedColumnIndex], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
                break;
            case SortOrder.Descending:
                dgv.Sort(dgv.Columns[sortedColumnIndex],
                                        ListSortDirection.Descending);
                break;
                // SortOrder.None - or anthing else - do nothing
        }
    }

    dgv.Rows[index.Value].Selected = true;
    dgv.Rows[index.Value].Cells[0].Selected = true;
    dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = firstDisplayedRowIndex;
    // Call any code that needs to know the selection might have changed
}
```